# Requesting verification of this arguably complex SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'd appreciate it if some SQL experts can take a look at this script and verify if it will work or if it can be improved in anyway (performance, ease, etc.). So, considering the following:

```
Leads {
    LeadId INT,
    SourceId TINYINT,
    PersonId INT,
    PhoneId INT,
    EmailId INT,
    AddressId INT,
    ImporterId SMALLINT,
    ImportedDateTime DATETIME2(7)
}

Duplicates {
    DuplicateId INT,
    SourceId TINYINT,
    LeadId INT,
    ImporterId SMALLINT,
    DuplicatedDateTime DATETIME2(7)
}
```

How will this script perform:

```
--  Outside variables provided as part of a stored procedure
DECLARE @SourceId TINYINT;
DECLARE @ImporterId SMALLINT;

PRINT 'Deleting the CSVTemp table if it exists';
IF ((SELECT CASE WHEN OBJECT_ID('CSVTemp') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [CSVTemp];
END

PRINT 'Creating the CSVTemp table';
CREATE TABLE [CSVTemp](
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(48),
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(48),
    [Phone] BIGINT,
    [Email] VARCHAR(96),
    [Street] VARCHAR(64),
    [Zip] INT
);

PRINT 'Performing a BULK insert into CSVTemp';
BULK INSERT [CSVTemp] FROM '{File}.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');

PRINT 'Adding IDENTITY column to CSVTemp';
ALTER TABLE [CSVTemp] ADD [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL;

PRINT 'Adding PK constraint to CSVTemp';
ALTER TABLE [CSVTemp] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_CSVTemp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    [Id] ASC
) WITH(
    PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ON [PRIMARY];

PRINT 'Counting CSVTemp rows';
DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [CSVTemp]);

PRINT 'Declaring internal variables';
DECLARE @I INT = 0;

PRINT 'Looping through rows in CSVTemp';
WHILE (@I < (@Count + 1))
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(48);
        DECLARE @LastName NVARCHAR(48);
        DECLARE @Phone BIGINT;
        DECLARE @Email VARCHAR(96);
        DECLARE @Street VARCHAR(64);
        DECLARE @Zip INT;

        SELECT  @FirstName = [FirstName],
                @LastName = [LastName],
                @Phone = [Phone],
                @Email = [Email],
                @Street = [Street],
                @Zip = [Zip] FROM [CSVTemp] WHERE ([Id] = @I);

        DECLARE @LeadId INT = (
            SELECT  [Leads].[LeadId]
            FROM    [People].[Person]
                    JOIN [Management].[Leads] ON ([Leads].[PersonId] = [Person].[PersonId])
                    JOIN [Communication].[Phones] ON ([Leads].[PhoneId] = [Phones].[PhoneId])
            WHERE   (([Person].[FirstName] LIKE @FirstName) OR ([Person].[LastName] LIKE @LastName))
                    AND ([Phones].[PhoneId] = @Phone)
        );

        IF (@LeadId IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [Management].[Duplicates]([SourceId], [LeadId], [ImporterId]) VALUES(@SourceId, @LeadId, @ImporterId);
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [People].[Person]([FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName);

            DECLARE @PersonId INT = @@IDENTITY;

            INSERT INTO [Communication].[Phones]([PhoneTypeId], [Number]) VALUES(6, @Phone);

            DECLARE @PhoneId INT = @@IDENTITY;

            INSERT INTO [Communication].[Emails]([Address]) VALUES(@Email);

            DECLARE @EmailId INT = @@IDENTITY;

            INSERT INTO [Location].[Addresses]([PostalCode], [Street]) VALUES(@Zip, @Street);

            DECLARE @AddressId INT = @@IDENTITY;

            INSERT INTO [Management].[Leads]([SourceId], [PersonId], [PhoneId], [EmailId], [AddressId], [ImporterId]) VALUES(@SourceId, @PersonId, @PhoneId, @EmailId, @AddressId, @ImporterId);
        END
    COMMIT

    SET @I = (@I + 1);
END

PRINT 'Deleting CSVTemp table';
DROP TABLE [CSVTemp];
```

**UPDATE**

@Will/@Mitch, I don't know if you guys are still around, but I ended up finalizing the script by converting the `WHILE` loop to work with a `CURSOR`. I tested the script by looping through 10.5k rows and it took 3-5 seconds, which is fine with me. Sadly, I thought I *fully* understood what @Will was saying about the sets, but I couldn't come up with a way to improve it, so I'll leave it as is. If anyone is willing to give me an example script about what @Will was talking about, I would appreciate it, if not, then thank you @Will and @Mitch for the help so far.

Anyway, here's the updated `WHILE` loop that uses a `CURSOR` now.

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 0;
DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR (SELECT [Id] FROM [CSVTemp]);

OPEN C1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @Id;

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(48);
            DECLARE @LastName NVARCHAR(48);
            DECLARE @Phone BIGINT;
            DECLARE @Email VARCHAR(96);
            DECLARE @Street VARCHAR(64);
            DECLARE @Zip INT;

            SELECT  @FirstName = [FirstName],
                    @LastName = [LastName],
                    @Phone = [Phone],
                    @Email = [Email],
                    @Street = [Street],
                    @Zip = [Zip] FROM [CSVTemp] WHERE ([Id] = @Id);

            DECLARE @LeadId INT = (
                SELECT  [Leads].[LeadId]
                FROM    [People].[Person]
                        JOIN [Management].[Leads] ON ([Leads].[PersonId] = [Person].[PersonId])
                        JOIN [Communication].[Phones] ON ([Leads].[PhoneId] = [Phones].[PhoneId])
                WHERE   (([Person].[FirstName] LIKE @FirstName) AND ([Person].[LastName] LIKE @LastName))
                        AND ([Phones].[Number] = @Phone)
            );

            IF (@LeadId IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO [Management].[Duplicates]([SourceId], [LeadId], [ImporterId]) VALUES (@SourceId, @LeadId, @ImporterId);
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO [People].[Person]([FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName);

                DECLARE @PersonId INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                INSERT INTO [Communication].[Phones]([PhoneTypeId], [Number]) VALUES(6, @Phone);

                DECLARE @PhoneId INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                INSERT INTO [Communication].[Emails]([Address]) VALUES(@Email);

                DECLARE @EmailId INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                INSERT INTO [Location].[Addresses]([PostalCode], [Street]) VALUES(@Zip, @Street);

                DECLARE @AddressId INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                INSERT INTO [Management].[Leads]([SourceId], [PersonId], [PhoneId], [EmailId], [AddressId], [ImporterId]) VALUES(@SourceId, @PersonId, @PhoneId, @EmailId, @AddressId, @ImporterId);
            END
        COMMIT

        FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @Id;
    END
CLOSE C1;
DEALLOCATE C1;
```

Comment: @Mitch, there's a code review site as part of StackExchange?

Comment: You're effectively taking a cursor-based approach to solve this problem, without actually using cursors.  Whilst this might work, it's not elegant (either with or without proper cursors).  Try to find a set-based (i.e. not row-by-row) approach to solving this problem.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Will, huh, when did this come to be? Guess I'll start using it from now on.

Comment: @Mitch, @Alex - I did wonder whether my suggestion was overkill for what could be a simple 'load a handful of rows' query - but I would suggest, Alex, that it's better to get into the habit of doing it right.  If you really want row-by-row processing, use SSIS.

Comment: @Will/@Mitch, is there any good links to tutorials (that you're fond of) about working with sets so I can get familiar with them?

Comment: @Will A: is correct. A set based solution will probably perform better than a cursor based approach; but in saying that make sure you have a performance problem before you try and speed it up! Measure first.

Comment: @Alex - sets aren't some magical construct in SQL, by 'set' we just mean a set of rows resulting from (or referenced by) a query.

Comment: @Will, so in my code, would the set be the `CSVTemp` table?

Comment: The CSVTemp table is just one set.  You've then got sets for e.g. the duplicate records based on matches vs. existing records, the set of people from the CSV etc.

Comment: @Will, I see. I think I understand, but it's pretty late for me to work on the script again (the code above was like 3 hours of brainstorming), so, I'll be back tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `@@IDENTITY`. Use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

> SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return
>   the last identity values that are
>   generated in any table in the current
>   session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY
>   returns values inserted only within
>   the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not
>   limited to a specific scope.
>
> For example, there are two tables, T1 and
>   T2, and an INSERT trigger is defined
>   on T1. When a row is inserted to T1,
>   the trigger fires and inserts a row in
>   T2. This scenario illustrates two
>   scopes: the insert on T1, and the
>   insert on T2 by the trigger.
>
> Assuming that both T1 and T2 have
>   identity columns, @@IDENTITY and
>   SCOPE_IDENTITY will return different
>   values at the end of an INSERT
>   statement on T1. @@IDENTITY will
>   return the last identity column value
>   inserted across any scope in the
>   current session. This is the value
>   inserted in T2. SCOPE_IDENTITY() will
>   return the IDENTITY value inserted in
>   T1. This was the last insert that
>   occurred in the same scope. The
>   SCOPE_IDENTITY() function will return
>   the null value if the function is
>   invoked before any INSERT statements
>   into an identity column occur in the
>   scope.